# get_template_directory() returns wrong address on VPS

Tags: urls, htaccess, directory, get-template-part, filesystem

I'm having the following problem with a Wordpress installation on a VPS server. I'm trying to read from a JSON file but the returned address from `get_template_directory()` is wrong:

```
$url = get_template_directory() . '/inc/includes/acf-fonticonpicker';

$json_file = trailingslashit($url) . 'icons/selection.json';

if($wp_filesystem->exists($json_file)){

   $json_content = $wp_filesystem->get_contents($json_file);

}
```

**$json_file** is empty because the JSON file is not found.
The returned address is:

```
/var/www/domainname/data/www/domain/wp-content/themes/couponhut/inc/includes/acf-fonticonpicker/icons/selection.json
```

and the file is exactly there,

What I'm doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could just get the json by `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data on your server with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). If you want to make sure the file exists and is readable then use [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php). You don't really need to use [`trailingslashit()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit) in this case because you're constructing the URI yourself.

```
// path to file under current theme 
$json_file = get_template_directory() . '/inc/includes/acf-fonticonpicker/icons/selection.json';

// make sure the file exists and is readable
if ( is_readable( $json_file ) ) {

    // pull the data but don't give an error if there is a problem
    if ( ! empty ( $json_content = @file_get_contents( $json_file ) ) ) {

        // convert to an array
        $json_array = json_decode( $json_content, true );
    } else {
        // show error message here
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `file_get_contents()` might be flagged in [Theme Check](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/).

File systems are funny, if you know it exists then it's possible that `/` and `\` need to be swapped in the path on occasion.

```
// BEFORE
// /vagrant/site/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/inc/includes/acf-fonticonpicker/icons/selection.json

$json_file = str_replace('/', '\\', $json_file);

or

$json_file = str_replace('/', '\\\\', $json_file);

// AFTER
// \vagrant\site\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\inc\includes\acf-fonticonpicker\icons\selection.json
```

Another way is to access via the url.

```
// url of file
$json_file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/includes/acf-fonticonpicker/icons/selection.json';

// request the file
$response  = wp_remote_get( $json_file );

try {
    // Note that we decode the body's response since it's the actual JSON feed
    $json = json_decode( $response[ 'body' ], true );
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    $json = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with `wp_remote_fopen` and it worked but is it the *correct* way to handle such situations?

Comment: @No, only reading from it.

Comment: It just dawned on me. You might need to reverse the slash direction for local file system. Give that a try.